# How to run php script while adding text to same html page?

Tags: php, html

So basically, I want to have someone complete a form, run a php script, and instead of pulling up the php file's web page, I want to append text at the end of the form.

Currently, I have a form:

```
<form action="scripts/email.php" method="POST">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
<p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
<p>Message: </p>
<p><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

When 'Submit' is clicked, it leads to my PHP script:

```
<?php

$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = "comp@c0mp.org";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail($to, $subject, "Name: " . $name . "\nMessage: " . $message, "From:" . $from);

print "Your message has been sent!";

?>
```

which leads to a blank web page that just says this in plain text:

"Your message has been sent!"

Basically, what I want is text added onto the submit form after the script is ran, such as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zha4d.png

How can I achieve running a PHP script on a web page, and instead of loading a new web page of the PHP script's path, but append text on the current HTML web page?

Comment: You need to use AJAX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: Check jquery's ajax function.  Bind to the submit function of the form.

Comment: See the answer below it works perfectly as your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS :** WRITE THIS CODE INTO A SINGLE PAGE.

```
<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF ;?>" method="POST">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
        <p>Message: </p>
        <p><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'] ))
        {
          $from = $_POST['email'];
          $to = "comp@c0mp.org";
          $subject = $_POST['subject'];
          $name = $_POST['name'];
         $message = $_POST['message'];

 mail($to, $subject, "Name: " . $name . "\nMessage: " . $message, "From:" . $from);

         echo "Your message has been sent";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly. Can you point me to some documentation on $PHP_SELF as I'd like to know what exactly it does.

Comment: Here ,$PHP_SELF is for targeting the same page .For example if this code is written in 'index.php'. Then $PHP_SELF is index.php.

It is similar to the refresh the page .If you don't like $PHP_SELF then you can use file name in which you write this code i.e.-index.php

You can use `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` to see what value PHP_SELF gives.

Comment: @Compressions : ANYtime bro... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax for acheive more secure and fast execution of script.

HTML code:

```
<form method="POST">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
        <p>Message: </p>
        <p><textarea id="area" name="message"></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="mail_js();">
</form>
<div id="success_msg" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Just give proper style to this div.

JS code:

```
function mail_js()
{

    var input_val=$('#name').val();
    var email_val=$('#email').val();
    var subject_val=$('#subject').val();
    var message_val=$('#area').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                'input_val':input_val,
                'email_val':email_val,
                'subject_val':subject_val,
                'message_val':message_val
            },
            url: 'email.php',

            success:function(response){

                $("#success_msg").append(response).show();
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert('error');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
```

PHP script:

```
$from = $_POST['email_val'];
$to = "comp@c0mp.org";
$subject = $_POST['subject_val'];
$name = $_POST['input_val'];
$message = $_POST['message_val'];

mail($to, $subject, "Name: " . $name . "\nMessage: " . $message, "From:" . $from);

echo "Your message has been sent";
```